# how to disable trailing spaces in emacs calender buffer

Tags: calendar

[image]

how to remove the red area that i think related to trailing spaces

Comment: Don't unconditionally enable `show-trailing-whitespace` everywhere. It doesn't make any sense in buffers derived from `special-mode` because those aren't text you're supposed to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`(add-hook 'calendar-mode-hook
          (function (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil))))`

Answer (score 0):

CAVEAT:  Deleting the trailing whitespace *may* have unintended consequences; e.g., there *might* be a function *somewhere* containing a regexp to locate a date and that regexp might include trailing spaces `"[0-9]+\s+"`.  If a problem arises, it will be necessary to either remove this `advice` or deal with the functions that are at issue.  Your mileage with this `advice` may vary.

```
(defun my-function (month year indent)
    (delete-trailing-whitespace))

(advice-add 'calendar-generate-month :after 'my-function)
```

Comment: Is the problem here not that `whitespace-mode` is enabled for the popup (quite possibly globally)? Just turning that off should fix the problem without having to modify the contents.

Comment: @RobertPluim -- While it is true that disabling `whitespace-mode` in `calendar-mode` buffers would make the trailing whitespace invisible to the human eye, it boils down to personal taste.  `whitespace-mode` makes some people "happy".   :)   I have modified several default functions in my own custom setup because I personally cannot live with one or more final new-lines in things like `dired-mode` and so forth.

Comment: I was not recommending turning it off completely, just for buffers in `calendar-mode`. Especially for generated buffers like calendars it makes little sense, and is less likely to cause other issues.